# Open Post Thumbnail in New Child Theme File in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, theme-development, wp-load.php

Today I am stuck in a new problem using WordPress Theme Development. What I'm going to do is to open a Thumbnail image in a new separate child theme, when the user clicks on the anchor tag.

**Example:**
[Click to Open Image](http://#)

and it redirects the user to the image on a separate theme file.

**Code Example for "single.php"**

```
<a href="PLZ MENTION CORRECT SYNTAX HERE" ); ?>">link to Another Page </a>
```

**Child Theme File "single-attachment.php"**

```
<?php 
/***
Template Name: Advertisement
***/

get_header(); ?>

<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Even though WP uses `thumbnail` in a log of functions, they're actually all considered `attachments` with regards to their post-type.  So `single-thumbnail.php` won't know what do.  You'll want to make the template in your child theme `single-attachment.php` instead.  I can't answer the first part of this for you because I have no idea how the image is getting added to the single.php, just that you want to make it a link.  Is it the 'featured image'?  Is it a custom field, are you manually building the link in the content editor?

Comment: It is a featured image @TonyDjukic

Comment: and actually, the file name is **single-ad.php** and not **single-thumbnail.php**. Sorry, my bad @TonyDjukic

Comment: That's not going to work.  You're targeting a thumbnail based on it's ID so the URL end up being the attachment permalink.  You don't appear to have made an `ad` custom post-type so `single-ad.php` also still doesn't know what to load.  You could spend hours coming up with a complex workaround but I'd advise against it.
Copy your `single-ad.php` file and name the new one `single-attachment.php`.  I'll post an answer for you.

Comment: Oh, Thank you for the positive advice @TonyDjukic. I'd change it from **single-ad.php** to **single-attachment.php**

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, neither `single-thumbnail.php` or `single-ad.php` will work in a simple manner.  Sure a complex solution/workaround could be written but it's totally unnecessary.  The template hierarchy in WordPress doesn't work that way.  Whatever follows `single-` in a `single-XXXXX.php` file is used to denote the content type/post type.  So the `single-ad.php` would only be used by WordPress if it was attempting to display an `ad` post type.

Instead, make a duplicate of `single-ad.php` and name the copy `single-attachment.php`.  Then go ahead formatting it however you like.

Now to get the url for your link you want to try the following:

```
<?php
    //First we get the ID of the Featured Image you attached to a post.
    $attachID       = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
    //Then we use that ID to get the permalink/url.
    //Not the URL of image file itself but of the attachment post type.
    $attachLink     = get_permalink( $attachID, false );
?>
<!-- Finally we echo out the permalink into our HREF tag -->
<a href="<?php echo $attachLink; ?>">Link to the Attachment Post</a>
```

That *should* address everything you need.

Here are the links to the functions I used:

- [Attachment Files/Post-Type](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/attachment-template-files/)
- [get_post_thumbnail_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_thumbnail_id/)
- [get_the_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/)

Comment: and what should we add to `single-attachment.php`? The above code redirect me to the image which I can got simply from `<?php the_permalink()?>`

Comment: Well you’d add the mark-up for how you want the page to be displayed.  Do you want the header, the footer, is there a sidebar, any other content, a title... that’s up to you.